# Argument Error for Date.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote this code:

```
[1,2,3,4].each do |f|
    @date = Date.new(2014,f * 3,1)
    @begin = @date.beginning_of_quarter
    @end = @date.end_of_quarter

    puts  f + " Quartal von " + @begin + " bis " + @end
end
```

Somehow i get the error:

```
 DateTest.rb:2:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (3 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from DateTest.rb:2:in `new'
    from DateTest.rb:2:in `block in <main>'
    from DateTest.rb:1:in `each'
    from DateTest.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

What did i wrong? Thanks!

Comment: This may be useful
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed three arguments to the original `Date.new`, which does not take any argument. The one that takes arguments is the one overwritten by the `"date"` library. In order to use it, you need to do

```
require "date"
```

Comment: Now i get  no more argument errors, but somehow it says `undefined method beginning of quarter`! Cab you help me?

Comment: That is not a Ruby method either.

Answer (score 1):

use `DateTime` instead of `Date` to initialize it with the parameters.  Check the API.  [Date](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html) & [DateTime](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html)

Comment: No need to use `DateTime` here